# Can't prevent default link action

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have a function in global scope as a link(`<a>`) handler:

```
function sort(e, field) {
e.preventDefault();

/*  sort process ...   */
}
```

And I have a link that appears **dynamically** in my HTML page:

```
<a onclick="sort(this,'title')" href="addr" id="sortByTitle">Book title</a>
```

Despite of e.preventDefault(); the link performs the default action anyway.

***Note:***
**It's very important that my link will be loaded via ajax.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use the onclick attribute, `return false;` will prevent the default action there.

```
<a onclick="sort(this,'title'); return false;" href="addr" id="sortByTitle">Book title</a>
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, I think you have an error somewhere else.  Please create a fiddle which can replicate your problem.

Comment: It should has been removed e.preventDefault(); in function handler and now it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try just using javascript without the html's "onclick"

```
function sort(e, field)
{
e.preventDefault();

/*  sort process ...   */
}
$("#sortByTitle").click(function(event) { sort(event, 'title'); });
```

Comment: When your javascript code is performing, link won't be loaded yet. I load it via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You must use addEventListener to listen to the click event, like so:

```
document.getElementById("sortByTitle").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Hello!!");
});
```

Take a look at this fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/rjnkuosL

edit:

**try this:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); sort();" />Book title</a>
```

Comment: When your javascript code is performing, link won't be loaded yet. I load it via ajax.